# How to set different widths for RecyclerView cells?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want a layout where the first cell is the full width of the RecyclerView, and the rest are half the width. There doesn't seem to be a built in function that lets me set this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with GridLayoutManager.

> By default, each item occupies 1 span. You can change it by providing a custom [`GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup) instance via [`setSpanSizeLookup(SpanSizeLookup)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager#setSpanSizeLookup(androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)).

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager

Comment: Sorry if this is a naive question, but where do I override `setSpanSizeLookup`?

Comment: You can make an anonymous class passed to `setSpanSizeLookup`. See [examples here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager&method=setSpanSizeLookup)

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. As a follow-up question, how can I set padding in between the cells that are in the same row? I tried setting the view's `layout_marginRight` by calling `setLayoutParams` on a new `LayoutParams` object but that didn't set the margins properly.

Comment: Try using padding instead, margin doesn't work for top level layout in recycler view items.